# computed property doesn't work with route param

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a getter where all products are stored there, and when I want to get only one product dynamically depending on `this.$route.params.id` it doesn't return any value

this code works correctly when I navigate to a certain product, but when I refresh the page I lose everything

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["getAllProducts"]),
        product() {
            return this.getAllProducts.filter(item => {
                return  item.id === this.$route.params.id;
            });
        }
    }
```

But if I supplied `filter()` with static value in instead of `this.$route.params.id` like below it works

```
        product() {
            return this.getAllProducts.filter(item => {
                return  item.id === 1;
            });
        }
```

I really don't know what is the problem, despite of in another component in my project I did some filters on some computed properties and it worked

**update: the routes config**

```
{
    path: "/product/:id",
    name: "product-page",
    component: ProductPage,
    props: true
}
```

Comment: what is the result of console.log(this.$route.params.id;) inside product() method?

Comment: it depends on the product i navigated to. It returns number as expected.

Comment: can you add const _self = this at the first of the product() method, and call _self.$route.params.id inside filter method()?

Comment: I tried it ofc. Still doesn't work.

Comment: please share the routes config

Comment: I just  updated it

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: your product id, is the id an integer or string ?

Comment: the id is  an integer

Comment: Hi, why did you deleted your question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844557/npm-init-nuxt-app-results-a-problem-failed-to-load-plugin-unicorn-declared-in?noredirect=1#comment132156710_74844557

Comment: sorry, i got it back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route params are usually parsed as strings.
Try converting the route param value to number type and then do the match:

```
product() {
    return this.getAllProducts
      .filter(item => item.id === Number(this.$route.params.id));
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't *parse* the number. You should only convert its type. In other words, you should use `Number(x)` rather than `parseInt(x, 10)`. Also note `+x` is equivalent to using `Number(x)` - they basically use the same code, under the hood.

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having. I was using `this.$route.params.id` in my function and refreshing the page was not returning the data I was fetching by that dynamic route :id

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) :

> When `props` is set to `true`, the `route.params` will be set as the component props

so add the `id` to your props like then use it instead of `this.$route.params.id` :

```
props:['id'], //refers to this.$route.params.id
...
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["getAllProducts"]),
        product() {
            return this.getAllProducts.filter(item => {
                return  item.id == this.id;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: that's right, the component   accepts the id as a prod, but still the code doesn't work

Comment: did you try it out without `props:true` and `this.$route.params.id`

Comment: Try out `return  item.id == this.id;` instead of `return  item.id === this.id;` remove one `=` to disable strict comparison

Answer (score -1):

Try giving this.$route.params.id as a computed propertly. Then call it in the filter method.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getAllProducts"]),
    routerId() {
     return this.$route.params.id;
    },
    product() {
        return this.getAllProducts.filter(item => {
            return  item.id === this.routerId;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems logical, but the params.id is a string so the `===` doesn't make a match, use a `==` or convert the params.id to a Number