# npm init nuxt-app results a problem "Failed to load plugin 'unicorn' declared in '.eslintrc.js » @nuxtjs/eslint-config'"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, vuex

I was trying to create Nuxt app using the command

> npm init nuxt-app

by installing the project, it results in this error

> npm init nuxt-app results a problem "Failed to load plugin 'unicorn' declared in '.eslintrc.js » @nuxtjs/eslint-config'"

while building the project as shown below

[image]

below my is my `.eslintrc.js` sitting,
can anyone plz help me

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false,
  },
  extends: ['@nuxtjs', 'plugin:nuxt/recommended', 'prettier'],
  plugins: [],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {},
}
```

Comment: I have a full ESlint + Prettier configuration explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585 Also, please share your project's settings. Or do you have just a basic Nuxt2 app?

Comment: I just added my nuxt.config.js file, may you help me plz

Comment: The interesting file here is `.eslintrc.js` tbh.

Comment: sorry, sir.
Here it is my `.eslintrc.js`, just updated it

Comment: Wait what? Do you have any unicorn or `eslint-config` anywhere? Do you have a public Github repo?

Comment: umm thank you so much for trying to help. I installed another node version (16.0.0) and all is good now.

Comment: @kissu May you help me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931062/i-need-to-cache-vuteify-theme-on-loacalstorage-i-use-nuxt-vuetify-app-but-it-do) plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Used another version of nodejs (16.0.0) and all is good.